# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

i am facing this problem here. i want to show item's name by getting its item id from another table. following is the code
i am having problem when i try to show name using ".$obj[0]->name." in the first line of the for loop.

```
$objClass = array(); 
$objClass1 = array();
$obj= array(); 
$object = new product();
$objLogic = new customerLogic();
$objLogic1 = new customerLogic(); 
$objL= new productLogic();
$objClass[0]= new stdClass;
$objClass1[0]= new stdClass;
$obj[0]= new stdClass;
$objClass[0]->custId = $_GET['id'];
$objClass1[0]->custId = $_GET['id'];

$objClass = $objLogic->getSaleRecord_customer($objClass[0]);
$objClass1 = $objLogic1->getName_customer($objClass1[0]);
$object->itemId = $objClass[0]->itemId;
$obj =$objL->getName_product($object->itemId); 
// echo $objClass1[0]->firstName;
$i=1;
foreach($objClass as $customer ) {
    echo "<tr><td class=\"inner_text\">$customer->reciept</td><td align=\"center\">".$obj[0]->name."</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\">".$objClass1[0]->firstName."&nbsp;".$objClass1[0]->lastName."</td><td align=\"center\">";
    echo "$customer->weight</td>
    <td align=\"center\">$customer->costPerKg</td>
    <td align=\"center\">$customer->cost</td>
    <td align=\"center\">$customer->payed</td>
    <td align=\"center\">$customer->remaining</td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you completely sure that `$objL->getName_product($object->itemId);` yields an object?

Could you verify that?

I think the return value of `$objL->getName_product($object->itemId);` is not what you think it is.

You can check it by `print_r($objL->getName_product($object->itemId));` which will give you a printout of the contents of that functions output.

Or maybe you are unintentionally overriding the contents of `$obj`?

Comment: thats the function i am using
public function getName_product($object)
 {
  $dbHandler = new dbConfig();
  $query="select name from product where itemId = $object";
  $results = $dbHandler->Query($query);
  return $results;
 }

Comment: Are you sure that this gives you an object representation and not an associative array? Have you tried `$obj[0]['name']`?

Comment: wow.. it is not showing error anymore but it dint show the name too? can u see any problem here

Comment: Is the data retrieved from database valid? And is the name non-empty in the DB? It might well be that the actual name *is* an empty string.

Comment: No problem. Hope you have got your answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `$obj`:

```
$obj =$objL->getName_product($object->itemId);
```

Comment: i am sorry i did not get what you are trying to say. I am new to php so kindly can you explain what should i do here

Comment: @talha you are making `$obj` an object, but then you are overwriting it in the line above. I don't know what that line is supposed to do so I can't give any real advice - maybe you just need to remove it or rename the variables